# Is this a rhododendron or an azalea and whats it called?

Tags: identification, rhododendrons, azaleas

I have this plant from my mothers garden after she passed, but not sure what it is or called it's either an *Azalea* or *Rhododendron*, but not sure which one.

[image]

Comment: Need to see the leaves/foliage to decide, as well as knowing the height and spread  (though a photo of the whole plant might  make that clear) but note  that,botanically,  azalea as a term no longer exists, all  are classified as Rhododendron. Is it in a pot or in the ground?

Comment: In the horticulture trade (in the US), rhododendrons that lose their leaves in the fall (deciduous) are still called azaleas; those that don't lose their leaves are called rhododendrons.

Answer (score 1):

Counting the stamens (about 10) shows it is a Rhododendron. Azaleas have about 5.
https://www.azaleas.org/azalea-basics/